# ViewPager does not updating the Fragment with updated content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i am suffering for 3 days. I'm using the View Pager from the compatibility library. I have successfully got it displaying several views .My Problem is that when i swap view then do not update data by fragment in its recycler view .But when i closed my application then opened fragments display update content by recycler view.i use all method like setnotifydatachanged() and many more but Fragment in viewpager does not update content.Thankx For any help 
    this is my main activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private ViewPager viewPager;
 private TabLayout tabLayout;
 @Override

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new              MainAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),MainActivity.this));
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    addIconsToTab();

}
       private void addIconsToTab() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        int drwableId = -1;
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                drwableId = R.drawable.home;
                break;
            case 1:
                drwableId = R.drawable.favourite;
                break;
            case 2:
                drwableId = R.drawable.watchlater;
                break;


        }
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(drwableId);
       }
    }
    }
   this is my main adapter 
   public class MainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  Context mContext;
   public MainAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    mContext=context;
  }

  @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new AllVideos();
        case 1:
            return new Favourite();
        case 2:
            return new WatchLater();

        default:
            return null;
     }
   }

@Override
 public int getCount() {
    return 3;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return mContext.getString(R.string.All_Videos);
        case 1:
            return mContext.getString(R.string.Favourite);
        case 2:
            return mContext.getString(R.string.Wtach_Later);
        default:
            return null;
    }
   }



   @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

    return POSITION_NONE;
  }
 } 
 And this is my Fragment
 public class Favourite extends Fragment {



  private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
  private FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter;



 RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup        container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview_carpaccio,     container, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)      {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    List<VideoInformationDataModel> videoinfo = db.getAllFavourite();
    favouriteAdapter = new FavouriteAdapter(getActivity(),videoinfo);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(favouriteAdapter);
    favouriteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),videoinfo.size()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


   }

  }

 And this is fragmentAdapter
  public class FavouriteAdapter extends        RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouriteAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{
     private int[] maid = {R.id.deleteoption};
    Context context;
    private List<VideoInformationDataModel> videoInformationDataModels;
   String videoid1;
    private FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter;
   public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements           View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView title;
    View root;
    protected ImageLoader img_uni_imageLoader;
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    ImageView networkImage,options;
    TextView Duration,Videoname;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        root = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoImage);
        Duration= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        Videoname= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VideoName);
        networkImage= (ImageView) itemView. findViewById(R.id.imgNetwork);
        options= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteoption);
        options.setOnClickListener(this);

      } 


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (maid[0] == view.getId()) {

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, options);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.deleteoption,           popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new          PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.delete:

                            int pos = getAdapterPosition () ;

                            videoid1=            videoInformationDataModels.get(pos).getVideoid();

                            db.deleteFavourite(videoid1);

                            videoInformationDataModels.remove(pos);
                            notifyItemRemoved(pos);

                            notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, getItemCount());


                            return true;


                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }


       }
    }


  public FavouriteAdapter(Context context, List<VideoInformationDataModel>       videoinformation) {

      this.videoInformationDataModels = videoinformation;
      this.context=context;


  }

  @Override
  public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.favouritesingleitem, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
   }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

         holder.Duration.setText(videoInformationDataModels.get(position).getVideoduratio   n());
         holder.Videoname.setText(videoInformationDataModels.get(position).getVideoinfo()    );
    holder.img_uni_imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
             .img_uni_imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
         holder.img_uni_imageLoader.displayImage(videoInformationDataModels.get(position)   .getVideoimg(), holder.networkImage);
    holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, YouTube.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();

            String Videtittle =     videoInformationDataModels.get(position).getVideoinfo();
            String videodes =      videoInformationDataModels.get(position).getFld_description();

            String duration =   videoInformationDataModels.get(position).getVideoduration();
            String videoid =    videoInformationDataModels.get(position).getVideoid();
              extras.putString("Videtittle", Videtittle);
            extras.putString("videodes", videodes);
            extras.putString("duration", duration);
            extras.putString("videoid", videoid);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            context.startActivity(intent);

             }
          });

        }





  @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position)
 {
    return position;
 }




 public int getItemCount() {
    return videoInformationDataModels.size();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what issue you are facing, but can you try once by replacing the FragmentPagerAdapter by FragmentStatePagerAdapter (extending by MainAdapter).

Comment: issue is that my dear i have 3 Fragment For example A,B and C  when app open first time then all fragments have updated data.but after when i added video in fragment B then it does not update its video list .if i close my app and reopen then Fragment B updates its Video list

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand exactly what your issue is, It might be a result of wrong implementation. But if you have tried `favouriteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and it still doesn't refresh.

You might as well remove the view, refresh it and add the view back and see if that works.

```
           ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) viewPager.getParent(); // get the view parent
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(viewPager); // remove the view
                viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify that the data has changed
                parent.addView(viewPager); // then, re-add the view
            }
```

Comment: issue is that my dear i have 3 Fragment For example A,B and C when app open first time then all fragments have updated data.but after when i added video in fragment B then it does not update its video list .if i close my app and reopen then Fragment B updates its Video list

Comment: Yea, thats why i said you should create a method and put my answer it in, Call that method after you added the video, so your view will be removed and re-added.

Comment: When you update the data, do you check the data size to see if it truly got updated?